# c50 code called exit with value 1

Tags: r

I keep getting an issue `"c50 code called exit with value 1"`.

when I do a summary on my model

```
Call:
C5.0.default(x = new_train[, -13], y = new_train$scored)


C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Sat Aug 18 04:23:51 2018
-------------------------------

*** line 7 of `undefined.names': `:' or `:=' expected after attribute name `Da Capo'

Error limit exceeded
```

I thought R isn't liking colons in the names, so I removed all of them. (In excel)

My data looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   178 obs. of  13 variables:


$ animeID: int  1 5 6 7 8 15 16 17 18 19 ...
 $ name   : chr  "Cowboy Bebop" "Cowboy Bebop Tengoku no Tobira" "Trigun" "Witch Hunter Robin" ...
 $ genre  : chr  "Action" "Action" "Action" "Action" ...
 $ genre.1: chr  " Adventure" " Space" " Sci-Fi" " Magic" ...
 $ genre.2: chr  " Comedy" " Drama" " Adventure" " Police" ...
 $ genre.3: chr  " Drama" " Mystery" " Comedy" " Supernatural" ...
 $ genre.4: chr  " Sci-Fi" " Sci-Fi" " Drama" " Drama" ...
 $ genre.5: chr  " Space" "" " Shounen" " Mystery" ...
 $ genre.6: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ genre.7: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ genre.8: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ genre.9: chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ scored : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

So I followed some of the other posts here and fixed the "" values in my different genre columns. With levels(credit$genre)[1] = "missing" for each respective genre column. But I still get the same issue.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this'll help ya or not, but when I get this message I usually:

1. Assign it to a variable despite the message.
2. Look at a summary of it to see if it tells me anything else.

   mdl = C5.0.default(x = new_train[, -13], y = new_train$scored);
   summary(mdl)